# Express multivariate normal as a univariate normals

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, univariate

I want to find the univariate normals of a multivariate normal in order to plot them. If we assume that each are independent, then I know that we can use the mean vector and diagonal of the covariance of the multivariate normal can be used as the means and variances of those independent univariate normal distributions.

Is it same to assume so or are there any other technique to derive the univariate normals of a multivariate normal?

I appreciate any help resolving the above doubt.

Comment: Are you talking about determining all the 1-dimensional marginals?  If so you can get them by integrating out all the other components from the joint distribution.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I guess so. According to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Marginal_distributions) the marginal distribution of multivariate normal distribution is derived by dropping the irrelevant variables. Therefore, can't I just used the individual mean and variance of each variable to find its 1-dimensional marginal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comment:

> Therefore, can't I just used the individual mean and variance of each variable to find its 1-dimensional marginal?

This is exactly what you can do. To see this in the case for a bivariate normal
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}X_1 \\X_2 \end{array}\right) \sim N_2\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}\mu_1 \\\mu_2 \end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{cc}\sigma^2_1 & \sigma_{12} \\ \sigma_{12} & \sigma^2_2 \end{array}\right) \right)\,. $$

Let $\rho = \sigma_{12}/\sigma_{1} \sigma_2$. The [pdf of this random variable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html) is

$$ \Tiny f(x_1, x_2) = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sigma_2 \sigma_2 \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}} \exp \left\{-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\left( \dfrac{(x_1 - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma^2_1}  - \dfrac{2\rho(x_1 - \mu_1)(x_2 - \mu_2)}{\sigma_1 \sigma_2} + \dfrac{(x_2 - \mu_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2} \right)\right\} \,.$$

To obtain the marginal distribution of $X_1$, we integrate out $X_2$. You can find a proof of that [here](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~ig/MTH5118/Notes11-09.pdf). For the multivariate normal case, you can find a proof [here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node7.html).

Comment: +1 -- but the proof is dead simple.  It amounts to observing that after integrating out all the other variables, the integrand is still the exponential of a quadratic form in the remaining variable and that its leading term and linear term do not change. (That is, there's no need actually to perform the integration or even to write out the PDF explicitly.) Those facts uniquely determine the answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a multivariate normal with means $\mu$ and covariance matrix  $\Sigma$, then the univariates ([marginals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Marginal_distributions)) are simple normals with corresponding mean $\mu_i$ and the variance $\Sigma_{ii}$: $$x_i\sim\mathcal N(\mu_i,\Sigma_{ii})$$